# How to ensure that the docker build fails if an ENV has not been set?

Tags: docker

[This github discussion](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/434) was found. It seems that it is allowed to build a docker image while a certain ENV does not have been set.

How to ensure that the docker build fails if an ENV has not been set?

Comment: `RUN 'if [ -Z $ENV ]; then exit 1; fi'` ?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to see that docker build itself denies it

Comment: Why that ? An empty of non existent environment variable is the same thing, there's no reason Docker do not allow you to pass an empty variable as it could be a very valid use case... It's up to your responsibility to ensure needed environment variables are there and give an error message back when not.

Comment: @Tensibai perhaps you could combine both comments and post it as an answer so it could be accepted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty of non existent environment variable is the same thing, there's no reason Docker do not allow you to pass an empty variable as it could be a valid use case.

It's up to your responsibility to ensure needed environment variables are there and give an error message back when not.

Something like this:

```
RUN if [ -z "$AN_ENV_VAR" ]; then echo 'Environment variable AN_ENV_VAR must be specified. Exiting.'; exit 1; fi
```

You can play with the exit code to automate some actions on failure around your `docker build` command.

Comment: Quotes in the RUN command are unneeded and error-prone

Comment: @CharlesB  Wasn't the case if you had `;` in your RUN command 4 years ago... A bit lazy to try it again right now TBH.

Comment: I had errors trying it just now, but without quotes it wet well

Comment: Indeed, I didn't escape singles quotes within the command back then. Well, feel free to edit

Answer (score 4):

To error out the build, just add the following with your env variable in the docker-compose file.

```
${ENV_VAR?Variable ENV_VAR not set}
```

example:

```
image: consul:${TAG?Variable TAG not set}
```

Comment: Thanks! Used this and it works great. I guess OP asked about Docker and not Docker Compose. Still, this worked great for me as I am using Compose.

Answer (score 1):

If the `if` command construct is very complex for you, you can always simply it like

```
RUN [ -n "$VAR" ]
```

This asserts the variable value length is nonzero. If it's empty or not set it'll exit with 1. This is also same as running `RUN test -n "$VAR"`

I see this error message on my machine

```
The command '/bin/sh -c [ -n "$VAR" ]' returned a non-zero code: 1
```